# How to color the sites favicon in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, colors, tabs, icons

I try to color the tabs URLs icons to red (just the icons of the sites).

[Icons I want to color to red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is6f7.png)

Used this code:

`.tabbrowser-tab .tab-icon-image { filter: sepia(1) saturate(5000%) hue-rotate(0deg); }`

[explanation of CSS hue-rotate Function](https://www.quackit.com/css/functions/css_hue-rotate_function.cfm)

But it's partially succeeded. All the webs icons with one color as github, virusetotal...are colored in red, but all the webs with more than one color as google, amazon.. are colored partially in red. It as like this code can color only one color of the icon.

[colored and not colored icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze3my.png)